# Creating a new Dataframe with specific row numbers from another

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, dataframe

I've found other posts that refer to creating a new dataframe using specific conditions from another (like ID = 27, etc.) but nothing that allows me to make a new dataframe from specific row numbers of another.

Here is what I have tried so far:

To add a single row to a new dataframe:

```
test.append(original.loc[300])
test
```

To add a list of rows to a new dataframe:

```
entries_to_move = [10, 20, 30]
for i in entries_to_move:
   test.append(original.loc[i])
test
```

Neither method works, so help would be appreciated. The output for either code is just a __.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, your question is to instantiate a new data frame `df2` from another data frame `df1`, by simply selecting rows.

You can do this by indexing. What is great by pandas DataFrames is that you can index a DataFrame using a list of indices.

```
df2 = df1.iloc[[list of indices],:]
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about the end : and kept getting an empty df2.

Comment: Thank you, the last ':' I missed and lost quite a good amount of time.